# How to create custom for loop in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am new to `NodeJS` and `ExpressJS`. I want to create custom `for` loop for traversing through the from the `NodeJS` data via `index` like we are using for not `for` loop.

Check below code from `NodeJS` where I am getting all users of role `User` and passing users to `handlebars` view.

```
exports.getAll = function (req, res) {
    models.Users.findAll({
        where: {
            role: {$ne: "User"}
        }
    }).then(users => {
        return res.render('users/index', {users: users});
    }).catch(error => {
        return res.json(error);
    });
};
```

Checkout my handlebars view. From below code I am able to traverse through all the users, but I don't want to use like that.

I want to use like we are using normal `for` loop `for(index = 0; index < count(users); index++`

```
<table class="table table-hover table-light">
    <thead>
        <tr class="uppercase">
            <th class="col-md-2"> Login </th>
            <th class="col-md-6"> Description </th>
            <th class="col-md-2">  </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each users}}
        <tr>
            <td> {{username}} </td>
            <td> {{about_me}} </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="#basic" data-toggle="modal" href="#basic" class="btn btn-blue btn-xs">Edit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried creating helper function. Check below code

```
hbs.registerHelper('for', function(from, to, incr, block) {
    var accum = '';
    for(var i = from; i < to; i += incr)
        accum += block.fn(i);
    return accum;
});
```

Is it possible to create normal `for` loop in `handlebars` template engine?

Can anyone help me to create new helper function?

Comment: What's wrong with your `for` helper function which you have created?. Why do you want to create another one?

Comment: I want to do `for(index = 0; index < count(users); index++)` like this from the view

Comment: You mean instead of `#each` ?

Comment: Yes, I want index of each record

Comment: Considering `users` as an object in your case, Can you try placing `{{@key}}` inside your `#each` block?

Comment: Thanks, It worked..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `{{@key}}` in order to use the `index` value inside your loop,

For example,

```
<tbody>
    {{#each users}}
    <tr>
        <td> {{username}} - {{@key}} </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Hope this helps!